# role is not in role list(if role in abc/else) it dont works

Tags: discord.py

I tried to make a addrole command but it didn't worked.I mean when role is not in role list(if role in abc/else) it dont works I dont know why pls help.

```
@client.command() 
async def addrole(ctx, user: discord.Member, role: discord.Role): 
    if ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
        abc = ctx.guild.roles
        xx = user.roles

        if role in abc:
            if role not in xx: 
                 await user.add_roles(role)
                 await ctx.send(f'{user.mention}, {role} Verildi')
            else:
                 await ctx.send(f'The User already have the role)
        else:
             await ctx.send(f'The role you are looking for is not in the server')

    else:
         await ctx.send(f'You Have not enough permissions to run this command')
```

Comment: "the code is not working" is not very specific. Can you please [edit] your question to let us know what the expected result is and how your code fails to achieve it? [Reading this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may be useful

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to see if the role exists would be to use `discord.Utils.get`

`discord.Utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Role-Name")`
Returns `None` if role with said name doesn't exist.